# Asset Function without Symfony in Twig

Tags: php, templates, web, twig

I'd like to use the asset function into my project where I'm only using Twig.
I tryed to use it but php return me this :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'Unknown "asset" function in "./Default/base.html.twig"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is on [sensiolabs.org](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/1.3/cookbook/assets.html).

I added this in `conf.php`:

```
//config/config.php
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

//twig
Twig_Autoloader::register();
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('../app/views');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFunction(new \Twig_SimpleFunction('asset', function ($asset) {
    // implement whatever logic you need to determine the asset path

    return sprintf('../assets/%s', ltrim($asset, '/'));
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because Assetic itself is a standalone PHP library.
 So to use `asset` in twig you need to install the bundle.

Run the following composer command to install **assetic bundle**.

```
composer require symfony/assetic-bundle
```

Without installing the standalone package, twig won't able to find the **asset** function.

Comment: and I have to configure it ?

Comment: Yes then you need to configure the stand-alone package.

Comment: how ? Do you have a link for a tutorial ?

Comment: I've not integrated it yet. May be these two links could help you. https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic https://github.com/saxulum/saxulum-assetic-twig-provider

Comment: `Package symfony/assetic-bundle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/webpack-encore-pack instead.`